Working with large parameters in an integer linear program using pulp
In pulp's documentation https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_debug.html, it says that

Check the precision of the numbers. If you have very big numbers (with a high precision), this generally causes problems with solvers. For example, never use a parameter that is 100000000000 inside your problem.

The problem is that my LP has parameters this large. Is there some transformation I can do to the problem that will help? I tried scaling the parameters by dividing all by the same large number, but then I end up with very small decimal values for some of the parameters as only the right side of each equation/inequality is large. An example constraint is 3*x + 4*y == 10000000000 where x and y must be integers.
Here is a more complete set of my code
f = open('data\input13_test.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
cost = 0
for i in range(0, len(lines), 4):
    a_coeff_eq_1 = int(lines[i].split(':')[1].split(',')[0].split('+')[1])
    a_coeff_eq_2 = int(lines[i].split(':')[1].split(',')[1].split('+')[1])
    b_coeff_eq_1 = int(lines[i+1].split(':')[1].split(',')[0].split('+')[1])
    b_coeff_eq_2 = int(lines[i+1].split(':')[1].split(',')[1].split('+')[1])
    c_eq_1 = int(lines[i+2].split(':')[1].split(',')[0].split('=')[1]) + 10000000000000
    c_eq_2 = int(lines[i+2].split(':')[1].split(',')[1].split('=')[1]) + 10000000000000
    
    a_coeff_eq_1
    a_coeff_eq_2
    b_coeff_eq_1 
    b_coeff_eq_2
    c_eq_1
    c_eq_2
    
    prob = LpProblem("MyProb", LpMinimize)
    a = LpVariable("a", 0, None, LpInteger)
    b = LpVariable("b", 0, None, LpInteger)
    prob += a_coeff_eq_1 * a + b_coeff_eq_1 * b == c_eq_1
    prob += a_coeff_eq_2 * a + b_coeff_eq_2 * b == c_eq_2
    prob += 3*a + b
    prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=1))
    if LpStatus[prob.status] == 'Optimal':
        for v in prob.variables():
            if v.name == 'a':
                cost += 3*v.varValue
            elif v.name == 'b':
                cost += v.varValue
            print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
            
print(cost)

The coefficients on a and b can be quite small compared to the cs.
Sample from input file
Button A: X+51, Y+11
Button B: X+38, Y+78
Prize: X=16146, Y=3706


You can address this issue by scaling the problem. Solvers often perform better when the numerical range of the coefficients in your Linear Programming (LP) problem is small.

So, how to do that? Divide each term by the same number? Then I will get a very precise decimal for some of the coefficients and I believe that will also cause an issue.

We can't give a specific description if you don't give a specific minimum reproducible example.

@Reinderien, I can appreciate that. I hope the code I added helps. Thanks for the call out.

Can you please also show a representative excerpt of your text file?

Yes. Done, @Reinderien.

To your 'prize' parameters you're adding 10 trillion. Why?

@Reinderien, it's a puzzle. No practical reason.

So the requirement for this large number is external it sounds like. If the puzzle has a problem statement can you please include it in your question?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This problem has a single analytic integer solution that has nothing to do with linear programming:
import io
import re
import typing


DELTA = int(1e13)


class Params(typing.NamedTuple):
    a1: int
    a2: int
    b1: int
    b2: int
    c1: int
    c2: int

    @classmethod
    def from_match(cls, match: re.Match) -> typing.Self:
        return cls(
            a1=int(match['a1']),
            a2=int(match['a2']),
            b1=int(match['b1']),
            b2=int(match['b2']),
            c1=int(match['c1']),
            c2=int(match['c2']),
        )

    @property
    def delta_term(self) -> int:
        """
        An integer solution is possible if this is 0.
        This is true for the only sample provided.
        """
        a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 = self
        return a1 + b1 - a2 - b2

    def solve(self) -> tuple[
        int,  # x
        int,  # y
        int,  # offset
    ]:
        a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 = self
        num1 = c2*(a1 + b1) - c1*(a2 + b2)
        denom1 = b2*(a1 + b1) - b1*(a2 + b2)
        delta_term = self.delta_term

        if delta_term == 0:
            xoff = num1//denom1
            x = (c1 - b1*xoff + DELTA)//(a1 + b1)
        else:
            xoff = (num1 + DELTA*delta_term)/denom1
            x = (c1 - b1*xoff + DELTA)/(a1 + b1)

        return x, x + xoff, xoff

    def errors(self, x: int, y: int) -> tuple[int, int]:
        a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2 = self
        return (
            a1*x + b1*y - c1 - DELTA,
            a2*x + b2*y - c2 - DELTA,
        )


param_pat = re.compile(r'''(?ix)
    Button\ A:\      # first line
    X(?P<a1>         # named capture group
        [+\-][0-9]+  # integer with explicit sign
    ),\              # intermediate space
    Y(?P<a2>         # named capture group
        [+\-][0-9]+  # integer with explicit sign
    )\s*             # newline
    
    Button\ B:\      # second line
    X(?P<b1>         # named capture group
        [+\-][0-9]+  # integer with explicit sign
    ),\              # intermediate space
    Y(?P<b2>         # named capture grooup
        [+\-][0-9]+  # integer with explicit sign
    )\s*             # newline
    
    Prize:\          # third line
    X=(?P<c1>        # named capture group
        [0-9]+       # integer without sign
    ),\              # intermediate space
    Y=(?P<c2>        # named capture group
        [0-9]+       # integer without sign
    )
''')


def parse_all(f: typing.TextIO) -> typing.Iterator[Params]:
    return map(Params.from_match, param_pat.finditer(f.read()))


def main() -> None:

    with io.StringIO('''
Button A: X+51, Y+11
Button B: X+38, Y+78
Prize: X=16146, Y=3706''') as f:
        param, = parse_all(f)

    print('For single sample input of')
    print(param)

    x, y, xoff = param.solve()

    print('y - x =', xoff)
    print(f'x = {x:,}')
    print(f'y = {y:,}')
    print('errors:', param.errors(x, y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

For single sample input of
Params(a1=51, a2=11, b1=38, b2=78, c1=16146, c2=3706)
y - x = -311
x = 112,359,550,876
y = 112,359,550,565
errors: (0, 0)


I see what you're saying. I think I'll give this a try and get back to you. Thanks for such a thoughtful and thorough answer.
